# GWTP, why ScrollPanel doesn't work in UiBuinder in Firefox?

Tags: css, gwt, scrollbar, uibinder, gwtp

I got Test.u.xml

```
<g:ScrollPanel addStyleNames="{style.happy-user-message}"><g:Label ui:field="happyLabel" text="lot of text her........" /></g:ScrollPanel>
```

my Css file has

```
.happy-user-message{
width:100%;
height:20px;}
```

When printing out it understood the css so only some text got display, but i didn't see any scrollbar in Firefox, in Chrome it's ok?

Why?

If I code ScrollPanel on the fly (without usin UiBinder) then there no problem?

Comment: Is your style in a css file unrelated with your uibinder?

Comment: no, if i increase the height to 40px, then this time it shows the scrollbar.